# Error: Warning: pack(): 1 arguments unused

Tags: javascript

Hi i want to send transaction with createTx function. When the value is higher than 4294967296 i got an error
Error: Warning: pack(): 1 arguments unused, if number is lower the transaction completes ok.

When using a rather large number (4295) which translates in 4295000000 HASH fails when sending a transaction.

This is because of the pack method arguments that are used in case the value is >= 4294967296
pack would be called like pack('@', 4295000000) which gives the warning

The code which translates is here:

```
    function binToHex(value) {
        let i, l, o = '', n;
        value += '';
        for (i = 0, l = value.length; i < l; i++) {
            n = value.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
            o += n.length < 2 ? '0' + n : n;
        }
        return o;
    }

function intToHexHandler(firstFormat, firstValue, secondFormat, SecondValue) { return binToHex(pack(firstFormat, firstValue)) + (secondFormat ? binToHex(pack(secondFormat, SecondValue)) : ''); } 

function intToHex(value) {
  if (value < 250) return intToHexHandler('C', value);
  else if (value < 65536) return intToHexHandler('C', 250, 'v', value);
  else if (value < 4294967296) return intToHexHandler('C', 251, 'V', value);
  else return intToHexHandler('C', 252, '@', value);
}
createTx({
  to,
  value,
  fee,
  nonce,
  data = ''
}) {
  const dataHex = binToHex(data);
  const message = to.substr(2) + intToHex(value) + intToHex(fee) + intToHex(nonce) + intToHex(data.length) + dataHex;

  const hash = sha256(encHex.parse(message));
  const sign = this._keyPair.sign(hash.toString(encHex)).toDER('hex');

  return {
    to: to,
    value: String(value),
    fee: String(fee),
    nonce: String(nonce),
    data: dataHex,
    pubkey: this.publicKey,
    sign: sign
  }
}
```

THe pack function is here:
https://github.com/xboston/metahash-js/blob/1e0caad6b18c5580c5173a77529af70b9885b8bf/dist/metahash.js#L22866

And the wallet js is here:
https://github.com/xboston/metahash-js/blob/1e0caad6b18c5580c5173a77529af70b9885b8bf/src/Wallet.js

Do you have any idea what arguments need to be given to the pack method in case of hash >= 4294967296?

Comment: Where do you call `pack()`? Where are `intToHexHandler()` and `binToHex()` defined?

Comment: function intToHexHandler(firstFormat, firstValue, secondFormat, SecondValue) {
     return binToHex(pack(firstFormat, firstValue)) + (secondFormat ? binToHex(pack(secondFormat, SecondValue)) : '');
 }

Comment: Don't put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: This is the code:
https://github.com/xboston/metahash-js/blob/1e0caad6b18c5580c5173a77529af70b9885b8bf/src/Wallet.js#L54

and pack:
https://github.com/xboston/metahash-js/blob/1e0caad6b18c5580c5173a77529af70b9885b8bf/dist/metahash.js#L22866

Comment: So this is a third-party library you're using? Maybe you should ask the author.

Comment: Yes thank you i did ask but has no clue so i am posting this here if someone can help me. Anyway thank you for your fast respose,

Comment: You need to edit the question to provide the context. No one is going to know what any of these functions are.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but where is the button for editing?

Comment: `Share
Edit
Follow
Close
Flag` right below the question.

Comment: The question still doesn't define or call `pack()`. It contains no link to the MetaHash project.

Comment: @karikato It's likely because that's the largest value you can have in an unsigned long (4 bytes).

Comment: I know that something is along this lines but dont know how to handle this action to work. Also edited the question with links.

Comment: I don't think `@` is the right packing code. Using that, it should be called as `intToHexHandler('C', 252, '@')` but that means the value wouldn't be encoded. I don't know how the rest of the program expects values >= 2^32 to be encoded. The javascript version of `pack` [comes from php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) which in turn [comes from perl](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack).

Comment: I found hat there is possible problem with longInt use. Long data type contain integer numbers that are too large to fit in the Integer data type. Is this possible

Comment: I also found that '@' is bound to that funcion here in the code:
https://github.com/xboston/metahash-js/blob/1e0caad6b18c5580c5173a77529af70b9885b8bf/dist/metahash.js#L23210